# Sound effect in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to **play a music from the phone song collection**.

Does the **sound effect properties support playing from the song collection**?

Previously **i used the media player to play the song but i want to set the music to not pause-able**.

Code for sound effect : 
            SoundEffect effect;
            SoundEffectInstance instance;

```
        effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(ml.Songs[songSelectedIndex]);
        instance = effect.CreateInstance();
        instance.IsLooped = true;
        instance.Volume = 1.0f;
        instance.Pitch = 1.0f;
        instance.Play();
```

Code for media library :

```
        using (var ml = new MediaLibrary())

        {
            FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
            MediaPlayer.Play(ml.Songs[songSelectedIndex]);
            MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Song` is a class that contains the music stream and can only be played with the Media Player. The reason your code isn't working is because the [FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.fromstream.aspx) method requires the stream to be:

> - A PCM wave file
> - Mono or stereo
> - 8 or 16 bit
> - Between 8,000 Hz and 48,000 Hz sample rate

I haven't tried this, nor know what the certification guidelines make of it, but you might be able to make the music unpauseable with the `MediaPlayer`. Handle the [MediaStateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.mediastatechanged.aspx) event and check if the music is paused. If it is, then call the [Resume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.resume.aspx) method to continue playing.

Edit - Update with code:

Handling the MediaStageChanged event is the same as any other event.

```
MediaPlayer.MediaStateChanged += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(MediaPlayer_MediaStateChanged);
```

In your event handler, do this:

```
void MediaPlayer_MediaStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MediaPlayer.State == MediaState.Paused) MediaPlayer.Resume();
}
```

Comment: I tried to research on how to use the mediaStateChanged but i didnt really find a sample on it. Do you have an example?