# Adding two music sources in WP7 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mediaelement

In my `WP7` gaming app , I want two music files to run. One is the background music and another follows the user action , say, user kills the enemy. I am using `MediaElement` to do this. I am facing two issues.

1) How to loop background music ?

2) As soon as second music starts, the first music stops and does not start back when the second music stops. I do not want background music to stop, they should overlap. How to do this ?

I am using silverlight.

**XAML**

```
<MediaElement x:Name="stroke"   AutoPlay="False" />
<MediaElement x:Name="bmusic"   AutoPlay="True" />
```

**C#**

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (settings.Contains("bm"))
        {
            string hy=(string)settings["bm"];
            //check if user has disabled music play
            if (hy == "1")
            {
                bmplay = 1;
                // play background music
                bmusic.Source = new Uri("bmusic.mp3", UriKind.Relative);

                bmusic.Play();

            }
            else
            {
                bmplay = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            bmplay = 1;
            // play b music
            bmusic.Source = new Uri("bmusic.mp3", UriKind.Relative);

            bmusic.Play();
        }



        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out msg))
        {
           //  textBox1.Text +=" "+ msg;
             find_move();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For repeating music you can use this:

```
Song s = Song.FromUri("song", new Uri(path));
FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
MediaPlayer.IsRepeating = repeat;
MediaPlayer.Play(s);
```

And try to use SoundEffect for sounds, they can be played simultaneously with background music.
[Sound effect in windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966017/sound-effect-in-windows-phone-7)

Comment: does this code work for silverlight ? i am getting errors at `song` and `mediaplayer`

Comment: you have to use proper path to your file. I use as path "Resources/Alarms/Alarm05.wma" - the file is then located in folder Resources/Alarms. You might also need the ID_CAP_MEDIALIB capability added to the WMAppManifest.xml file.